# Multiple Point Selection chartJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

I'm trying to draw graphs with multiple datasets in chartJS. Some datasets are grouped together and users should be able to select those grouped datasets with a single click on the group.

Example:

*Before select*
[image: Before select]

*After select*
[image: After select]

Is this possible in chartJS?
Thanks

Comment: Yes this is possible by using scriptable options

Comment: thanks for the reply ... As I'm new to chartJs, do you have an example?